# `errorformat` pattern for multiple messages on same line

Tags: errorformat

I am trying to `set errorformat=...` so that I can parse errors like the following:

```
error: cannot format /home/user/repo/src/file1.py: Cannot parse: 2:5: some source code here
error: cannot format /home/user/repo/src/file2.py: Cannot parse: 7:10: some_more source code here
Oh no!   
2 files failed to reformat.
```

(For context, this error is produced by the python [black](https://github.com/psf/black) code formatter. I am writing `CompilerSet makeprg=black` and `CompilerSet errorformat=...` in the file `~/.vim/compiler/black.vim`, for use with the [vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) plugin).

My question is about how to set `errorformat` so that the output in the quickfix window contains all the relevant pieces of information. Ideally, all of the following should be printed in the quickfix window:

- `cannot format`
- `Cannot parse`
- `source code...`

I've had some success with setting

```
errorformat=error:\ cannot\ format\ %f:\ %s:\ %l:%c:\ %m
```

which results in the following quickfix output:

```
file1.py|2 col 5| some source code here
file2.py|7 col 10| some_more source code here
|| Oh no!   
|| 2 files failed to reformat.
```

I have also tried

```
errorformat=error:\ cannot\ format\ %f:\ %m:\ %l:%c:\ %s
```

which results in

```
file2.py|7 col 10| Cannot parse
file1.py|2 col 5| Cannot parse
|| Oh no!   
|| 2 files failed to reformat.
```

Ideally, the quickfix output should look something like this:

```
file2.py|7 col 10| cannot format: Cannot parse: some source code here
file1.py|2 col 5| cannot format: Cannot parse: some_more source code here
|| Oh no!   
|| 2 files failed to reformat.
```

Printing this additional information would be useful to me in quickly debugging the problem(s) in the quickfix list.

I've tried variations on using multiple `%m` and `%s` symbols; all of the following give errors:

- `error:\ cannot\ format\ %f:\ %m:\ %l:%c:\ %m`
- `error:\ cannot\ format\ %f:\ %s:\ %l:%c:\ %s`
- `error:\ %m\ %f:\ %m:\ %l:%c:\ %m`

Any ideas?

Comment: In a tangentially-related issue, I'm having trouble using `:cnext` with the above. Vim jumps to the correct file but not to the correct line-number. Not sure if it's related to the errorformat...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the text you want to see in the message field of the quickfix list is disconnected in the original output:

```
error: cannot format /home/user/repo/src/file1.py: Cannot parse: 2:5: some source code here
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Try to filter the errors first, with some script, to format the output so that all these parts are connected:

```
# before
error: cannot format /home/user/repo/src/file1.py: Cannot parse: 2:5: some source code here
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

# after
/home/user/repo/src/file1.py:2:5:cannot format: Cannot parse: some source code here
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It's easier to write an errorformat for the latter output; `%f:%l:%c:%m` should work.

See `:h errorformat-javac` for an example.

---

Here's one possible implementation.

Write this short sed script in `~/bin/vim-black-filter`:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

s/error: \(cannot format\) \(.*:\) \(Cannot parse: \)\([0-9]\+:[0-9]\+:\) \(.*\)/\2\4\1: \3\5/
```

Make the script executable, and make sure `~/bin` is in your path:

```
$ chmod +x ~/bin/vim-black-filter
```

Then, in your compiler plugin `~/.vim/compiler/black.vim`, write this:

```
let current_compiler = 'black'

if exists(':CompilerSet') != 2
    com -nargs=* CompilerSet setl <args>
endif

CompilerSet mp=black\ 2>&1\ \\\|\ vim-black-filter
CompilerSet efm=%f:%l:%c:%m
```

---

> In a tangentially-related issue, I'm having trouble using :cnext with the above. Vim jumps to the correct file but not to the correct line-number. Not sure if it's related to the errorformat...

It's probably because you used `%s` in your errorformat.

Whatever text is matched by `%s`, it's used to populate the `pattern` field of a quickfix list entry.  In turn, this field is used to locate the error line.  And the `pattern` field has priority over the `lnum` one.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I hadn't thought to try preprocessing `black`'s output before passing it to vim.