# Keep matched filename, line number and column number in the error message

Tags: python, errorformat

I'm currently trying to create some errorformat rules to parse the output of the [black formatter](https://github.com/psf/black). The output of this formatter is as follows:

```
would reformat /home/ricks/Development/personal/errorformat/fmts/testdata/resources/python/num_guess.py
would reformat /home/ricks/Development/personal/errorformat/fmts/testdata/resources/python/subfolder/queen_problem.py
Oh no!   
256 files would be reformatted.
Oneword.
```

With the help of [@filbranden](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/18609/filbranden) (see [this question)](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/28300/ignore-lines-with-string-in-errorformat) I designed the following errorformat syntax to parse this:

```
%-GOh no!%.%#
%-G%\d\+ file%.%#
%m %f
%-G%.%#
```

You can see this parsing in action on [the following playground](https://reviewdog.github.io/errorformat-playground/?efms=%25-GOh%20no%21%25.%25%23%0A%25-G%25%5Cd%5C%2B%20file%25.%25%23%0A%25m%20%25f%0A%25-G%25.%25%23&text=would%20reformat%20%2Fhome%2Fricks%2FDevelopment%2Fpersonal%2Ferrorformat%2Ffmts%2Ftestdata%2Fresources%2Fpython%2Fnum_guess.py%0Awould%20reformat%20%2Fhome%2Fricks%2FDevelopment%2Fpersonal%2Ferrorformat%2Ffmts%2Ftestdata%2Fresources%2Fpython%2Fsubfolder%2Fqueen_problem.py%0AOh%20no%21%20%F0%9F%92%A5%20%F0%9F%92%94%20%F0%9F%92%A5%0A256%20files%20would%20be%20reformatted.%0AOneword.). After I asked the question I, however, noticed that the black formatter could also throw an error when it finds a syntax error:

```
error: cannot format /home/ricks/Development/personal/gh-actions/action-black/testdata/num_guess.py: Cannot parse: 12:6: test===jan
would reformat /home/ricks/Development/personal/gh-actions/action-black/testdata/subfolder/queen_problem.py
Oh no!   
1 file would be reformatted, 1 file would fail to reformat.
```

I am therefore trying to improve my errorformat rules such that it also parses the error message. I came up with the following error syntax to parse this error (see this syntax in action [on the following playground](https://reviewdog.github.io/errorformat-playground/?efms=%25trror%3A%20%25.%25%23%20%25f%3A%20%25.%25%23%3A%20%25l%3A%25c%3A%20%25m%0A&text=error%3A%20cannot%20format%20%2Fhome%2Fricks%2FDevelopment%2Fpersonal%2Fgh-actions%2Faction-black%2Ftestdata%2Fnum_guess.py%3A%20Cannot%20parse%3A%2012%3A6%3A%20test%3D%3D%3Djan)):

```
%trror: %.%# %f: %.%#: %l:%c: %m
```

This, however, results in the error message that only contains the `test===jan` text where I want it to include any of the following:

- The full error message: `cannot format /home/ricks/Development/personal/gh-actions/action-black/testdata/num_guess.py: Cannot parse: 12:6: test===jan`
- A shorter error message: `Cannot parse: test==jan`.
- A custom error message: `Syntax error found: test==jan`.

I also tried the following syntax `%trror: %.%# %f: %m: %l:%c: %m` but I can not get the relevant parts of the message together.

Judging from [this stack question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26083/errorformat-pattern-for-multiple-messages-on-same-line) the biggest problem with parsing this error message is that the text I want to see in the message field of the quick-fix list is disconnected in the original output:

```
error: cannot format /home/user/repo/src/file1.py: Cannot parse: 2:5: some source code here
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The question mentioned above suggests first pre-processing the black output (using regex) before passing it to the vim errorformatter. In my case, this is also possible but not easy. I was, therefore looking if there is a solution that doesn't require this pre-processing. I came up with the following solutions, but I can not get them to work:

1. Find a way (maybe through regex) to combine the separated parts into one error message.
2. Prase the filename(`%f`), line number (`%l`) and column number (`%c`) strings but also include them into the error message (`%m`).
3. Prefix the error message with some additional text (e.g. `A syntax error occured: : test===jan`.

#### Solution 1

According to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17375881/vim-errorformat-include-part-of-expression-in-message-string), this can be done using regex. I therefore first tried using the following errorformat syntax:

```
%trror: %\\%%(cannot\ format%\\)%\\@=%f: %.%#: %l:%c: %m
```

This, however, doesn't seem to work in [the playground](https://reviewdog.github.io/errorformat-playground/?efms=%25trror%3A%20%25%5C%5C%25%25%28cannot%5C%20format%25%5C%5C%29%25%5C%5C%40%3D%25f%3A%20%25.%25%23%3A%20%25l%3A%25c%3A%20%25m%0A&text=error%3A%20cannot%20format%20%2Fhome%2Fricks%2FDevelopment%2Fpersonal%2Fgh-actions%2Faction-black%2Ftestdata%2Fnum_guess.py%3A%20Cannot%20parse%3A%2012%3A6%3A%20test%3D%3D%3Djan). This is because the playground (and thus the error parser I'm using) doesn't support the Vim Regex syntax (see [this page](https://github.com/reviewdog/errorformat)).

#### Solution 2

I also did not find a way to match an expression but also include it into the error message. Judging for the solution above, this should also be possible using regex. As I could not get the regex solution to work with the playground, I also was not able to find the right syntax for also including the %f, %c, %l operators into the regex syntax.

#### Solution 3

I searched the forum, but I did not yet find a way to add some additional text to the error format message. I had something like this in mind:

```
%trror: %.%# %f: %m: %l:%c: %{A syntax error occurred:}m
```

#### Question

My main question, therefore, is: Do you think it is possible to achieve what I have in mind (without using regex)? If not, I will try to implement [the pre-processing](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26083/errorformat-pattern-for-multiple-messages-on-same-line) solution. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Not an answer to your question but an alternative approach that I take: black is meant to be a formatter, rather than a linter.  I use flake8 to lint my code (in fact, every time I write the file it runs flake8 and displays errors/warnings in the statusline and location list).  I only format right before committing.  Depending on your use case, you could run flake8 or similar prior to running black.

Comment: @AndrewHo-Lee Thanks for your comment. That's also what I'm using for my own actions. I'm however asking this question since I am trying to add the behaviour to an action that is used by multiple people. You, however, raise an excellent point. Since black is a formatter, and not a linter people generally do not expect to get very in-depth error messages. Catching the error as a fully parsed error message might therefore not be worth the effort. Nevertheless, since I'm curious to see if there is a solution I keep this question open a little longer.